# express-mutler always saves to temp folder

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying very simple file upload using mutler and express:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const formidableMiddleware = require('express-formidable');

const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

const app = express();

app.use(formidableMiddleware());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        console.log(dirPath);
        cb(null, dirPath);
     },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null , file.originalname);
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy")
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
    },
});
 
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))


app.use('/api/auth', authRoute);
// app.use('/api/todo', todoRoute);

app.post('/file/single', upload.single('profile'), (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.files);
  try {
    res.send(req.files);
  }catch(err) {
    res.send(400);
  }
});

app.post('/file/bulk', upload.array('profiles', 4) , (req, res) =>{
    try {
        // res.send(req.files);
    } catch(error) {
          console.log(error);
           res.send(400);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000')
})
```

This code always saves file in `temp folder`, i am new to this, what am I doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Does `console.log(dirPath);` log the correct path?

Comment: yes, console.log(dirPath); log the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Delete the onFileUploadStart in the storage definition:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        console.log(dirPath);
        cb(null, dirPath);
     },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null , file.originalname);
    },
});
```

Check the DiskStorage implementation: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/storage/disk.js

Answer (score 0):

its better to configure multer in the beginning like this :-

```
import multer from "multer";
import sharpe from "sharp";

const upload = multer({      //multer configuration
  dest: "/path/to/where/you/want/to/store/file",  //so that buffer is available in route handler
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000,   //can also specify size also
  },
  
});
```